# React Native Android restart app when crashes

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm working on an that needs to run in Kiosk Mode. I think I have covered every possible way so the user cannot leave the app, but I want some sort of safety net: in case the app crashes I need it to restart automatically.

I've been looking at guide on how to do it, but I haven't found one that I could translate to React Native.

I found [this](http://chintanrathod.com/auto-restart-application-after-crash-forceclose-in-android/) article particularly useful. However, I cannot replicate it entirely due to the fact that in React Native there isn't a .java Application file (or at least I haven't found one), so I can override the UncaughtExceptionHandler.

I can restart the app programmatically by calling this method:

```
public void restartApp(){
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
        .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

But I simple cannot call it when the app crashes.

Comment: React native app also have .java file. Go to your project => android => src => main => java => your package => MainActivity.java file

Comment: Finally figured out how and wrote an article about it: https://medium.com/@aeperea/setting-up-an-android-app-with-react-native-in-kiosk-mode-e062b309db71

Comment: If your device is rooted, you can use [app_watchdogd.sh](https://github.com/flyskywhy/app_watchdogd)